# Technical disavantages of application used on a windows network share/drive by multiple users

Tags: windows, application, network-share

Let's take a custom-made .NET application :

- Dependency on the .Net Framework
- A few dlls and an executable
- A few dependencies on third parties (Crystal Reports, Connector, etc.)

What are the technical disadvantages of installing this kind of application. on a network share or drive, and allow multiple users to use it at the same time on a windows domain ? I'm looking for usage issues, not deployment issues.

I know that it's not the best case scenario, and that, auto-updatable local installs, TS sessions and other means are now available for this situtation, but I'd like to have a clear and deep answer to discourage such way to install applications across a network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your actual application and setup you might run into

- file locking issues
- permission problems
- network performance bottlenecks
- availability issues

These might or might not be relevant to a specific installation. I would not claim that an executable on a network share is always a bad thing, but it is more prone to be than a local install.

Comment: I added some details on the kind of application I'm talking about, if that's of any help to precise the possible issues that could be encountered. But that's already a good answer, thanks :)